# How to set [i] in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't know to set [i] in the array.

[image]

```
statusResponse() {
  var dataStatus = this.$.xhrStatus.lastResponse;

      for(var i = 0; i < this.maxStatus; i++) {
        console.log(this.maxStatus);
        console.log([i]);
        console.log(dataStatus);
        console.log(dataStatus[fs_+ i +_P41001_W41001B]);
        this.userInfo.status({
          "branch_plant": this.$.xhrStatus.lastResponse.fs_ + 
[i] +_P41001_W41001B.data.gridData.rowset[0].sDescription_99.value
        });
      }
  }
```

Comment: `fs_` and `_P41001_W41001B` need to be strings, you are currently using them as if they are variables, ie `['fs_'+i+'_P41001_W41001B']`

Comment: I've put the variables for the array on between fs_ + i + _P41001_W41001B, then it started to get undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change:

```
dataStatus[fs_+ i +_P41001_W41001B]
```

to

```
dataStatus["fs_" + i + "_P41001_W41001B"]
```

**Explaination**

This is roughly how the computer understands it the following line:

1. Take string `"fs_"`
2. Add the variable `i` to it, so the string become `"fs_4"` (if `i` = 4)
3. Add `"_P41001_W41001B"` to it, so the string becomes `"fs_4_P41001_W41001B"`
4. Get `dataStatus["fs_4_P41001_W41001B"]`

**Updated code**:

```
statusResponse() {
  var dataStatus = this.$.xhrStatus.lastResponse;

      for(var i = 0; i < this.maxStatus; i++) {
        console.log(this.maxStatus);
        console.log([i]);
        console.log(dataStatus);
        console.log(dataStatus["fs_" + i + "_P41001_W41001B"]);
        this.userInfo.status({
          "branch_plant": this.$.xhrStatus.lastResponse["fs_" + i + "_P41001_W41001B"].data.gridData.rowset[0].sDescription_99.value
        });
      }
  }
```